# HTML link with "noopener" and/or "noreferrer" in Chrome/Chromium results in unexpected behaviour

Tags: chrome, firefox, chromium

There are several attacks possible when embedding links with `target="_blank"`. This is where `rel="noopener"` and `rel="noreferrer"` should help.

I am expecting that clicking the following link

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Google</a>
```

results in a new browser tab, with a new HTML5 session storage.

This works fine with Firefox 65.0, but not with Chromium 71.0 and Chrome 72.0.

The problem is, that with Chrome/Chromium the same HTML5 session storage persists.

Exactly the same behaviour can be observed when using `rel="noopener"` or `rel="noopener noreferrer"`.

The implementation state is listed at:

- https://caniuse.com/#feat=rel-noopener
- https://caniuse.com/#search=rel-noreferrer

My questions are:

- Is this behaviour appropriate?
- Am I missing something?
- How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

*Addendum (further observations):*

When right-clicking on the link in Chrome/Chromium and clicking either "Open link in new window" or "Open link in new tab", then there will also be created a new session storage. The same applies when holding the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key and clicking the link (= new tab) or holding the <kbd>shift</kbd> key and clicking the link (= new window).

Further reading:

- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-noopener
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-noreferrer
- https://www.thesitewizard.com/html-tutorial/open-links-in-new-window-or-tab.shtml
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709625/link-with-target-blank-and-rel-noopener-noreferrer-still-vulnerable
- https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage
- https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Why do you think that `noopener` or `noreferrer` should have any effect on the session storage? I couldn't find that in any of your links.

Comment: @Sjoerd I have added a link about the session storage. In general, a session storage gets associated with one particular browser window or browser tab. The added link states "Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated with the value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from how session cookies work." Thus, my observation was very unexpected. Furthermore, with Firefox I could observe the intended behaviour.

Comment: If I understand it correctly the session storage is copied to the new tab. So you get a new session storage instance with the same values as the original tab. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: @Sjoerd Yes, exactly, but only with Chrome/Chromium. Firefox works as expected.

Comment: See also [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=818389), [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=165452).

Comment: @Sjoerd There seems to be some controversy about the intended behaviour. What is now the expected behaviour? There are different attitudes. Please consider, that I have added the `rel` attribute with `noopener` and/or `noreferrer`, which is not mentioned in those discussions. Without this `rel` attribute Firefox, Chromium and Chrome show the same behaviour.